# How to add BACK button on JSFF page in Oracle ADF?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I am an Oracle ADF Developer. I want to add a BACK button on my JSFF page which can redirect me to the previous page. I searched the internet but could only find Javascript code which was not helpful. Could anyone suggest some java code which I can write a button action?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and get your first badge. Create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for clearity and add  code here

Answer (score 2):

What Joe has suggested is the way to do it. This is just a detailed answer.

Here are the steps:

1. Add a Control Flow Case from the current View(current JSFF) to previous View(previous JSFF) in the taskflow.
2. Set the 'From Outcome' property of the control flow case to something like 'Back'
3. Add a Button on the current JSFF page.
4. Set the 'Action' property of the button as 'Back' (same string from step 2)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply add a taskflow flow case back from the page to the previous page and tie a button to that?